# How to force a timeout on a HTTP request from php

Tags: php, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a website which spambots visit a lot. I would like to stop these spambots from skewing my website statistics with non-human requests.

I run IIS 7 (fast-CGI), mainly with PHP as the server side language. I have PHP code in place that detects what a spambot is, when it detects this spambot it doesn't log the entry to my request history log file. This solves the problem.

However I would like to punish the spambots further, and hopefully slow down/deter their requests.

**Is there any way I can NOT send a HTTP response to the spambot's HTTP request?**

In PHP I figured I would use a `sleep(30)` time out before calling `exit()` but I hear this still requires some server resources during the `sleep` i.e. keeping memory allocated to the script etc. Is there any way I can exit the PHP script, and essentially send nothing to the spambot? Which will hopefully lock it's request thread until the client side request timout it reached.

Comment: I dont think he wants to prevent it, but make the spammer waste time on the pages (see his `sleep(30)`)

Comment: I "hope" that a spambot has a little intelligence and should not return to a 404 page in the future :)